# How to get a mask of the pixels that were warped "from no where" in cv2.warp methods?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, perspectivecamera

This code warps my images fine

```
    kp1, des1 = self._detector.detectAndCompute(static, None)
    kp2, des2 = self._detector.detectAndCompute(moving, None)
    matches = self._matcher.match(des1, des2)

    assert len(matches) >= 4  # for perspective tform
    moving_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    static_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    tform, mask = cv2.findHomography(moving_pts, static_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
    tform = self._force_translation_only(tform)
    matches_mask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    matches_image = cv2.drawMatches(static, kp1, moving, kp2, matches, None,
                                    flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS,
                                    matchesMask=matches_mask,
                                    matchColor=(0, 255, 0),)

    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(moving, tform, (static.shape[1], static.shape[0]), flags=cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
```

and yields the following

[image: warped]

I would like a mask of the non black part, and of course doing `warped>0` is not good enough, as it would not capture truly black data pixels.

I'm sure there is a correct way to do this.

Comment: warp also a complete white image of the same size. Then you can mask out pixels in the original image according to the warped white image

Comment: @Miki I did that, before asking, but didn't bother mentioning because it is extremely inefficient. every warp is done twice! surely there is a better way. One I can think of, is warping only 4 corners, and doing Bresenham between them. I just don't want to implement and test that, because something has to be ready made for this.

Comment: you can warp the four corners (or use directly the four corners after warping if you know them beforehand) and create a mask with cv::fillPoly. Ore use a color for the constant border that you know it's not in the input image (works best with color image, using e.g. pure green)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Miki in comment, you could warp a white image of the same size.
But then the warp is done twice as you noted.

Instead, you can warp 4 corners and draw a white polygon with `cv2.polylines` but I'm not sure it will be more efficient than warping a white image.

Comment: It would not work, because the transform is a homography, and a rectangle would assume only a translation.
Unless I don't understand your suggestion about polylines.

Comment: You're right it's not a rectangle but a polygon. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: can you show code of what you mean please? In the end I need a mask at the static image which is the area to which the moving image is warped to